# Could someone tell me how I can expand a dropdown list?

Tags: html, css

In practice I have this list and I want to expand it from left to right here is an example photo

[image]

This is my dropdown list code:

```html
<table  id="select">
  <tr>
    <td> <select id="changec" onchange="select()" >
      <option selected value="t">Time</option>
      <option value="l">Length</option>
    </select> </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <tr>
  <table id="tbn1">
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="number" value=0 id="timeinput" oninput="calculateTime()"/> <br/><br/> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" value=0 id="timeresult"  readonly /><br><br> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: May we get the rest of the code? (at least the part that includes both inputs)

Comment: <tr>
    
    <td> <input type="number" value=0 id="timeinput" oninput="calculateTime()"/> <br/><br/> </td>

    <td> </td>

    <td> <input type="text" value=0 id="timeresult"  readonly /><br><br> </td>

   </tr>

Comment: hey, include your code with the question not here in the comment...

Comment: if you have css code then upload that to

Comment: Don't use tables for layout purposes. Tables are for displaying tabular data **only**.

Comment: So what can I do to put everything in order?

Comment: @Valy You got 2 answers yesterday. Please consider upvoting them.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "table" is "div". You can do the same with it and a bit more.
Here is your example:

```
<div id="select" style="width:100%">
    <select id="changec" onchange="select()" style="width:100%" >
        <option value="t" selected>Time</option>
        <option value="l">Length</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br />
<div id="tbnl" style="100%">            
    <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
        <input type="number" value=0 id="timeinput" oninput="calculateTime()" style="width:90%"/>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%; float:right">
        <input type="text" value=0 id="timeresult" style="width:90%; float:right" readonly />
    </div>
</div>
```

It is only an example because normaly you do not use the styles outside of a CSS. But the thing is you can shape a div-tag totally to your will.

Answer (score 0):

I have three positions: one is full width, one is pulled to the right with a hover and one is pulled to the two sides with a hover.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.row
{
   width:100%;
   padding:50px 10px;
   margin:10px;
   background-color:red;
   border:1px solid black;
}
.select1
{
    width:96.5%;
    height:40px;
}
.select2
{
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    transition:width 1s ease-out;
}
.select3
{
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    transition:width 1s ease-out;
}
.select2:hover
{
    width:96.5%;
}
.select3:hover
{
    width:92%;
}
.text-center{
    text-align:center;
    padding:50px 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <select class="select1">
       <option>option 1-------</option>
       <option>option 2-------</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <select class="select2">
       <option>option 1-------</option>
       <option>option 2-------</option>
   </select>
</div>


<div class="row text-center">
     <select class="select3">
       <option>option 1-------</option>
       <option>option 2-------</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same concept as in the other answer, but maybe more elementary markup:

```css
#select,#tbn1{margin-top:20px;text-align:center}
select{width:80%}
input{width:39%}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="select">
  <select id="changec" onchange="select()" >
    <option selected value="t">Time</option>
    <option value="l">Length</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="tbn1">
  <input type="number" value="0" id="timeinput" oninput="calculateTime()"/> 
  <input type="text" value="0" id="timeresult" readonly /> 
</div>
</body>
```